# How to download video from url and save in gallery?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, apple-tv

I have viewSettingsViewController, and I would like download movie from url which is found in textfield.

Below is screen of app:

[image]

Below is my code:

import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit
class SettingsViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet var urlLabel: UITextField!
let PlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()
var Player:AVPlayer?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    let videoUrl:NSURL = NSData(contentsOfURL:urllabel)

    if let url = videoURL {
        self.Player = AVPlayer(URL: url)
        self.PlayerController.player = self.Player
    }

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func downloadButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.presentViewController(self.PlayerController, animated: true) { 
        self.PlayerController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

}

Any suggest how to make this app ?

Answer (score -1):

All of this should be done in a different thread (**Not UI thread**).

This is the most basic way to download, if you want something better to suit your needs, try using *AFNNetworking* download.

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

// Write it to cache directory
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.mov"];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];


// After that use this path to save it to PhotoLibrary
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] completionBlock:^(NSURL *assetURL, NSError *error) {

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.description);
    }else {
        NSLog(@"Done :)");
    }
}];
```

Comment: Why did you vote down? Did it not work? Is it not the answer you are looking for? Please explain